# Check if a block device is Bitlocker encrypted

Tags: ubuntu, disk-encryption, whole-drive-encryption

Ubuntu 22.04 can decrypt and read a BitLocker-encrypted device/partition without a need of installing any additional software (older releases can as well, perhaps, but I have not seen it)

How can a block device or a partition be checked as to whether it is encrypted using **BitLocker** in a similar way a LUKS-encrypted device/partition can be verified using:

```
sudo cryptsetup isLuks /dev/sda1
echo $?
```

and

```
sudo cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sda1
```

I have tried watching the `dmesg` log, checking with `lsblk`, but none of them seem to indicate the encryption type.

My question is specific to Ubuntu 22.04, but answers for other distros will be helpful and are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lsblk` for that, `FSTYPE` column will be set to `BitLocker` (filesystem information is not shown by default, you need to use `-f` or `-o+FSTYPE`):

```
$ lsblk -f
NAME                                          FSTYPE      FSVER    LABEL UUID                                   FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
loop0                                         BitLocker   2
```

and if you need more information `cryptsetup bitlkDump` also exists:

```
$ sudo cryptsetup bitlkDump /dev/loop0
Info for BITLK device /dev/loop0.
Version:        2
GUID:           8f595209-f5b9-49a0-85d4-cb8f80258c27
Sector size:    512 [bytes]
Volume size:    104857600 [bytes]
Created:        Thu Jul  4 09:01:55 2019
Description:    DESKTOP-NPM7RCA H: 7/4/2019
Cipher name:    aes
Cipher mode:    xts-plain64
Cipher key:     256 bits
```

Comment: Haha, you beat me to it with the `lsblk -f` :) The cryptsetup one is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know it was the cryptsetup behind the scenes that enables BitLocker encryption to work seamlessly on Ubuntu. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `-f` option of `lsblk` shows info about the filesystem and for a BitLocker device, in my case, it states `BitLocker 2`

```
lsblk -f /dev/sda1
```

Also, `blkid` conveniently identified `TYPE="BitLocker"`

```
sudo blkid /dev/sda1
```

*(It is amazing what new ideas come to mind once you press that "Submit Question" button)*